# Chain select and max_by on json doc with jq in bash

Tags: json, bash, jq

I want to get the SnapshotIdentifier of the snapshot with the maximum SnapshotCreateTime, and filter it by ClusterIdentifier. Here is the command I'm using:

```
aws redshift describe-cluster-snapshots --region us-west-2 |
  jq -r '.Snapshots[]
         | select(.ClusterIdentifier == "dev-cluster")
         | max_by(.SnapshotCreateTime) 
         | .SnapshotIdentifier '
```

Here is the json

```
{
    "Snapshots": [        
        {
                "EstimatedSecondsToCompletion": 0, 
                "OwnerAccount": "45645641155", 
                "CurrentBackupRateInMegaBytesPerSecond": 6.2857, 
                "ActualIncrementalBackupSizeInMegaBytes": 22.0, 
                "NumberOfNodes": 3, 
                "Status": "available", 
                "VpcId": "myvpc", 
                "ClusterVersion": "1.0", 
                "Tags": [], 
                "MasterUsername": "ayxbizops", 
                "TotalBackupSizeInMegaBytes": 192959.0, 
                "DBName": "dev", 
                "BackupProgressInMegaBytes": 22.0, 
                "ClusterCreateTime": "2016-09-06T15:56:08.170Z", 
                "RestorableNodeTypes": [
                    "dc1.large"
                ], 
                "EncryptedWithHSM": false, 
                "ClusterIdentifier": "dev-cluster", 
                "SnapshotCreateTime": "2016-09-06T16:00:25.595Z", 
                "AvailabilityZone": "us-west-2c", 
                "NodeType": "dc1.large", 
                "Encrypted": false, 
                "ElapsedTimeInSeconds": 3, 
                "SnapshotType": "manual", 
                "Port": 5439, 
                "SnapshotIdentifier": "thismorning"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 7):

1. `max_by` expects an array as input.  Thus the following variant of your filter would work:

   ```
   [.Snapshots[] | select(.ClusterIdentifier == "dev-cluster")]
   | max_by(.SnapshotCreateTime)
   | .SnapshotIdentifier
   ```
2. Based on your verbal description, it would seem you want to run `max_by` before `select`:

   ```
   .Snapshots
   | max_by(.SnapshotCreateTime)
   | select(.ClusterIdentifier == "dev-cluster")
   | .SnapshotIdentifier
   ```
3. If there is possibly more than one maximal object, you might want to use `maximal_by` rather than `max_by`:

   ```
   def maximal_by(f):
     (map(f) | max) as $mx
     | .[] | select(f == $mx);
   ```

Comment: Thanks Peak, the first solution worked for me. @JeffMercado, thanks for helping me out again!